# Translation of "I am not good at reading people's minds"

Tags: expressions, traduction, adjectifs

> I am not good at reading people's minds.

Often, this kind of sentence is [translated](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18413/how-do-you-say-he-is-good-at-playing-or-i-am-bad-at-writing-in-french) by using a noun to refer to the activity that the person is good/not good at:

> They are good at cooking. -> Ils sont forts en cuisine.

For "reading people's mind", there's probably no noun that can replace it. Should the translation then be

> Je devine mal ce que d'autres personnes pensent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Je devine mal ce que d'autres personnes pensent* sounds well. Here are some alternatives:

> - J'ai du mal à lire dans les pensées.
> - Je devine mal ce que pensent les autres.
> - Il est difficile pour moi de deviner ce à quoi les autres pensent.

Comment: Je vote pour "J'ai du mal à lire dans les pensées". Simple et efficace: L'esprit plutôt que la lettre. Les autres propositions sont correctes d'un point de vue syntaxique, mais malheureuses d'un point de vue stylistique. (NB on dira plutôt "ce que pensent les autres" plutôt que "ce que(ce à quoi) les autres pensent"

Comment: @Vinny J'ai changé l'ordre de mes suggestions en mettant la plus pertinente en première. J'ai également corrigé la seconde selon ton "NB". Merci pour tes retours !

Comment: Est-ce que *ce que* ne serait pas mieux que *ce à quoi* pour la dernière phrase? L'importance est non pas sur le sujet des pensées, mais plutôt les pensées elles-mêmes.

Comment: @user11550 *Il est difficile pour moi de deviner ce que les autres pensent* est effectivement tout à fait correct aussi.

Answer (score 2):

> Je devine mal ce que d'autres personnes pensent.

is indeed possible and correct. Let's see if we could find something else...

> Je ne suis pas très fort pour lire (dans) les pensées des gens.

Or possibly:

> Lire (dans) les pensées des autres n'est pas mon fort.

The expressions *lire (dans) les pensées de qq'un* exists in French, so we can use it directly. The expression *lire les pensées* also exists, and [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lire+dans+les+pens%C3%A9es%2Clire+les+pens%C3%A9es%2C+deviner+les+pens%C3%A9es&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clire%20dans%20les%20pens%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clire%20les%20pens%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeviner%20les%20pens%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0) shows they are about equally frequent in terms of usage. One can also say *deviner les pensées de qq'un*, and all three expressions are pretty close in terms of usage frequency today.

[image]

Comment: Do we use *pour* after *fort*? This surprises me a bit, since I would think that *à* sounds better.

Comment: Hmmm - that _à_ does not sound natural at all to me :-) I think _pour_ sounds much better here.

Comment: In English "I am good *for* ..." would sound weird, but of course in French this could be totally different :=)

Comment: So, I am a French native speaker, and I would instinctively use _pour_, but now you have planted the seeds of doubt in my mind, and it is possible that I am using _pour_ in an incorrect fashion, when _à_ would be required to be completely correct. Or maybe that _à_ used to be correct, but that _pour_ is becoming more popular as a familiar form.

Comment: @user11550 - it looks like _pour_ sounds better when followed by a verb, and _à_ when followed by a noun, but that's only what my more or less familiar usage would be. It might be false or incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: In "Je devine mal ce que d'autres personnes pensent", should *personnes* or *gens* be used, or do both work?

Comment: @user11550 *Être fort pour* could be said but it doesn't mean what I think you want to say. *pour* introduces an aim ("in order to"), it does sound weird used with *très*. The fact is that *être fort* is used followed by a noun and not by a verb. So if you do  not want to use *Je devine mal ce que d'autres personnes pensent.* which to my mind is the best, I'd advise using *dans* followed by a noun (*Je ne suis pas très fort dans la lecture des pensées*).

Comment: Nice use of ngrams, especially since it shows my favorite (“Lire les pensées” withOUT the “dans”) on top! Anyway, +1 & [here’s something](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18413/#18416) that supports your gut instinct that “pour” works fine here where, as @Random mentions, it means more like "in this specific thing.” Random also proposes “doué,” which ain’t half bad either. (Hopefully my allusion to that earlier question won’t set off another mad rush to wrongly mark this one as a duplicate, for it clearly isn’t one, but I’m noticing more & more how that doesn’t seem to matter anymore)

Comment: @PapaPoule - yes - that use of _pour_ is probably familiar, or semi-incorrect but in use, as I noted above. Might be interesting to look into it. Agreed for the duplicates (or the so-called "cultural" questions). For the duplicates, at least we should transfer whatever is interesting into the original question, but that never happens, it's just "close, close, close".

Answer (score 0):

On peut rester très proche de la phrase d'origine avec :

> Je ne suis pas bon pour lire dans la tête des autres/pour lire dans la tête d'autrui.

Answer (score 0):

Au vu des réponses précédentes, on peut s'étonner que personne ne relève le fait qu'il est factuellement impossible, en français, de "lire dans les pensées des autres".

Cela fait une grosse différence avec les autres exemples "réalistes" du genre : "Tu peins bien"- "C'est un bon pilote", "Elle excelle en cuisine", etc.

Donc, on se situe ici quasi nécessairement dans le registre de l'humour, de l'ironie, du décalage.
Les propositions avancées précédemment, qui tentent de faire du littéral sont, dans ce cas de figure précis, vouées à l'échec.

Explorez d'autres voies, par exemple :
- "Excusez-moi, **je suis nul en** télépathie".
- "Lire dans les pensées, **ce n'est pas mon truc**".
- "**J'ai un mal fou à** rentrer dans la tête des autres, pas vous ?". 
- "**Je ne réussis pas encore à** deviner ce que les autres pensent".

Dans le registre moins fantastique du "You are reading my mind", on dira simplement :
- "Je ne sais **jamais** [ce que / à quoi] les autres pensent".

"Jamais" permet ici de restituer l'impossibilité ou difficulté exprimée par "not good at".

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of saying it (in casual French):

> Je ne sais/peux pas lire dans les pensées/dans la tête des gens.