# How do you say “what subject are you good/bad at”?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, questions

How do you ask “what subject are you good at or bad at” using the word *quelle* or *matière*? Because in google translate it comes up with “quel sujet es-tu bon ou mauvais?”

Answer (score 5):

You can find better than google where translations are concerned.
That's what [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/home) gives for "[What subject are you good at?](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/What%20subject%20are%20you%20good%20at%3F)":

> Dans quel domaine êtes-vous bon ?

With the options:

- Dans quel domaine es-tu bon ?
- Dans quel domaine es-tu doué ?

Which is correct because we did not give it any context and "subject" can indeed be translated by *domaine*.

If you give it more context [just by adding "at school"](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/What%20subject%20are%20you%20good%20at%20at%20school%3F), that's what you get:

> Dans quelle matière es-tu bon à l'école ?

The translator has recognised the school context and used *matière* and the *tu* form comes first since the question is more likely to be asked to a child or a teenager.

Some people say :

- En quelle matière es-tu bon ?

because that is how the adjectives *bon* and *mauvais* are used:

- Je suis **bon en** maths mais je suis **mauvais en** français.

You can also choose not to use the word *matière* :

- En quoi es-tu bon ?

You might also like to read the answer to this question [How do you say “He is good at playing” or “I am bad at writing” in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18413/358) for other ways to say "good at" and "bad at".